# How do I assign a 2D subset of my tensor with another 2D tensor in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

If I have two 3-D tensors `img` and `gen`. How do I assign a 2D subset of `img` with a 2D subset of `gen`? The following doesn't work as tensorflow doesn't allow direct assignment of tensors.

```
img[96:160 , 144:240 , :] = gen[96:160 , 144:240 , :]
```

**EDIT:**

This is the surrounding code. So I'm using a custom keras layer. This layer must receive the input image `img` and the generated image `x`. It must replace a portion of `img` with `x` and must return the modified `img`.

```
def patcher(tensors):
    img = tensor[1]
    gen = tensor[0]
    #This is where the slicing must happen
    img[96:160 , 144:240 , :] = gen[96:160 , 144:240 , :]
    return [img]

img = Input( .. )
x = Conv( .. )(img)
out = Lambda(patcher,lambda a : [a[1]] )([x , img])
model = Model(img, out)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remaining part of `x` should be assigned with `a1`"? How `x` is constructed in the first place? Please elaborate more. It is not clear what you want exactly.

Comment: @today I've edited the question. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: I have a solution for this; however the problem is that the batch size must be specified from the beginning in this solution. Otherwise, as far as I know, you can't do slice based assignment.

Comment: @today I'm using this statement inside my loss function. So the real dimension that the function receives is `(?,a,b,c)` where a,b,c are fixed

Comment: Do `img` and `gen` have the same shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot replace slices of a tensor in a straightforward manner. I actually [opened an issue about it](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18383) because it is something that people keep asking for. With the current API, you have to sort of figure out the best way to build the tensor you want. In this case, assuming `img` and `gen` have both the same shape, this is one way you could do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Input
img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
gen = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
row_start = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
row_end = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
col_start = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
col_end = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
# Masks rows and columns to be replaced
shape = tf.shape(img)
rows = shape[0]
cols = shape[1]
channels = shape[2]
i = tf.range(rows)
row_mask = (row_start <= i) & (i < row_end)
j = tf.range(cols)
col_mask = (col_start <= j) & (j < col_end)
# Full mask of replaced elements
mask = row_mask[:, tf.newaxis] & col_mask
# Select elements from flattened arrays
img_flat = tf.reshape(img, [-1, channels])
gen_flat = tf.reshape(gen, [-1, channels])
mask_flat = tf.reshape(mask, [-1])
result_flat = tf.where(mask_flat, gen_flat, img_flat)
# Reshape back
result = tf.reshape(result_flat, shape)
```

Here is a small test:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # img is positive and gen is negative
    img_val = np.arange(60).reshape((4, 5, 3))
    gen_val = -img_val
    # Do img[2:4, 0:3, :] = gen[2:4, 0:3, :]
    result_val = sess.run(result, feed_dict={
        img: img_val,
        gen: gen_val,
        row_start: 2,
        row_end: 4,
        col_start: 0,
        col_end: 3,
    })
    # Print one channel only for clarity
    print(result_val[:, :, 0])
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   3.   6.   9.  12.]
 [ 15.  18.  21.  24.  27.]
 [-30. -33. -36.  39.  42.]
 [-45. -48. -51.  54.  57.]]
```

---

EDIT:

Here is a possible implementation for the code that you have posted. I am using a slightly different method here based on multiplication, which I think is better when you have many images.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def replace_slices(img, gen, row_start, row_end, col_start, col_end):
    # Masks rows and columns to be replaced
    shape = tf.shape(img)
    rows = shape[1]
    cols = shape[2]
    i = tf.range(rows)
    row_mask = (row_start <= i) & (i < row_end)
    j = tf.range(cols)
    col_mask = (col_start <= j) & (j < col_end)
    # Full mask of replaced elements
    mask = row_mask[:, tf.newaxis] & col_mask
    # Add channel dimension to mask and cast
    mask = tf.cast(mask[:, :, tf.newaxis], img.dtype)
    # Compute result
    result = img * (1 - mask) + gen * mask
    return result

def patcher(tensors):
    img = tensor[1]
    gen = tensor[0]
    img = replace_slices(img, gen, 96, 160, 144, 240)
    return [img]

img = Input( .. )
x = Conv( .. )(img)
out = Lambda(patcher, ambda a: [a[1]])([x , img])
model = Model(img, out)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit new to tensorflow. I'm actually trying to do this assignment in my custom loss function, which receives `img` and `gen`. How exactly do I put this code in my loss function? I mean I don't need to write `sess.run` right?  So how will the test code change if I just need to write it in my loss function?

Comment: @NirvanAnjirbag Well I'm not sure how is your code, but no, I suppose you don't need the session, I was just trying to illustrate how it worked. What you need is the tensor `result`, which is `img` with the replaced slice. You can use that as you would normally use `img` or any other tensor. If you have doubts maybe you can post some more of your code for context.

Comment: I've added some more code in the edit. Please have a look. Sorry, not loss function, I mean a custom layer. This assignment must happen in my custom keras layer. So how do I exactly place your code in the function `patcher`?

Comment: @NirvanAnjirbag I'm not sure I understand your code... `Lambda` should receive one function, not two... And what are the shapes of `img` and `gen` in that context? I suppose at least `img` will have also a first batch dimension? So are the dimensions you want to slice really first and second?...

Comment: The second argument in `Lambda` is the shape.
`img` and `gen` have the same shape when received in `patcher` i.e `(?,256,384,3)` .
I want slicing to happen for every image in the batch. So basically my slice will be `[ : ,96:160 , 144:240 , :]`

Comment: @NirvanAnjirbag Well that's actually a slightly different problem. Can be solved in a similar manner although I'm not sure what's best. What is the shape of `gen`? Does it also have a batch dimension or is it a single image from where every image in the batch take the replacement?

Comment: `gen` also has a batch dimension. `img` and `gen` are both `(?,256,384,3)`. I want this replacement to happen for corresponding pairs of images in `gen` and `img`

Comment: @NirvanAnjirbag I have added an implementation for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I modified my initial solution, which only worked when the batch size was set, based on @jdehesa's solution. This should work in Keras across all the backends (TensorFlow, Theano and CNTK):

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

def replace_slices(ts, row_start, row_end, col_start, col_end):
    shape = K.int_shape(ts[0])[1:-1]
    np_mask = np.zeros(shape + (1,))
    np_mask[row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end] = 1.
    mask = K.variable(np_mask, dtype=K.dtype(ts[0]))
    # ts[0] is the img and ts[1] is the x tensor
    return ts[0] * (1 - mask) + ts[1] * mask

args = {'row_start': 96, 'row_end': 160, 'col_start': 144, 'col_end': 240}

img = Input(shape=(256,384,3))
x = Conv2D(3, (3,3), padding='same')(img) # this must have 3 filters since img has 3 channels
out = Lambda(replace_slices, arguments=args)([img, x])
model = Model(img, out)
```